# How to integrate $\int \sqrt{1-\dfrac{1}{25x^2}}\ dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How to integrate the following:

$$\int \sqrt{1-\dfrac{1}{25x^2}}\ dx$$

What I did is:

$$\int \sqrt{1-\dfrac{1}{25x^2}}\ dx=\int \dfrac{\sqrt{25x^2-1}}{5x}\ dx$$

I substituted $5x=\sec\theta$, $dx=\dfrac{1}{5}\sec\theta\tan\theta\ d\theta $

$$=\int \dfrac{\sqrt{\sec^2\theta-1}}{\sec\theta}\ \dfrac{1}{5}\sec\theta\tan\theta\ d\theta$$

$$=\frac15\int \tan^2\theta\ d\theta$$
used $\tan^2\theta=\sec^2\theta-1$
$$=\frac15\int( \sec^2\theta-1)\ d\theta$$
$$=\dfrac15\tan\theta-\frac15\theta+c$$
back to $x$
$$=\dfrac15\sqrt{25x^2-1}-\frac15\sec^{-1}(5x)+c$$

I am not sure whether my answer is correct.

My question: Can I integrate this with other substitutions? If yes, please help me. Thank you

Comment: I haven't checked the whole solution but you need to be careful about signs. For example, you used $\sqrt{25x^2} = 5x$, but this is only true when $x\geq 0$, and you should write $|5x|$ in general, and similarly for $\sqrt{\sec^2 \theta-1}$.

Comment: I have checked your answer comes out to be correct. You can differentiate your integral. You will get the same function in integration

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is correct.

You can use another substitution
$\dfrac{1}{5x}=\sin\theta\implies dx=\dfrac{-\cos\theta\ d\theta}{5\sin^2\theta}$

$$\int \sqrt{1-\dfrac{1}{25x^2}}\ dx=\int \cos\theta \left( \dfrac{-\cos\theta\ d\theta}{5\sin^2\theta}\right)$$
$$=\frac15\int (-\cot^2\theta) \ d\theta$$
$$=\frac15\int (1-\csc^2\theta) \ d\theta$$
$$=\frac15(\theta+\cot\theta)+C$$
$$=\frac15\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{5x}\right)+\frac15\sqrt{25x^2-1}+C$$

Answer (score 2):

you can also do it with $t^2=25x^2-1$. To get
\begin{align*}
\int \frac{\sqrt{25x^2-1}}{5x} \, dx&=\frac{1}{5}\int \frac{t^2}{t^2+1} dt\\
&=\frac{1}{5}\left[\int \frac{t^2+1-1}{t^2+1} dt\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{5}\left[t-\int \frac{1}{t^2+1} dt\right]\\
&=\frac{t}{5}-\frac{\arctan t}{5}+c,
\end{align*}
where $t=\sqrt{25x^2-1}$.

Comment: is your answer same as mine? please explain

Comment: @SamulGonjo It actually is the same answer written a bit differently. If we plug in $t=\sqrt{25x^2-1}$, then we get $\frac{\sqrt{25x^2-1}}{5}-\frac{\color{red}{\arctan \sqrt{25x^2-1}}}{5}+c$. Now the difference between your answer and mine is the inverse trig function used. For that let $\color{red}{\theta=\arctan \sqrt{25x^2-1}}$, then $\tan \theta=\sqrt{25x^2-1}$, which implies $\sec \theta=5x$ or $\color{red}{\theta=\sec^{-1}(5x)}$. Same as your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The domain of the integrand is
$$(-\infty,-\frac 15]\cup [\frac 15,+\infty)$$

Assume we want the antiderivative at $(-\infty,-\frac 15]$,

$$F(x)=\int \sqrt{\frac{25x^2-1}{25x^2}}dx=$$
$$-\frac 15\int \frac{\sqrt{25x^2-1}}{x}dx$$
Now you can put
$$5x=-\cosh(t)$$
with
$$\sqrt{25x^2-1}=\sqrt{\cosh^2(t)-1}=\sinh(t)$$

then

$$F(x)=-\int \frac{\sinh(t)}{\cosh(t)}\frac{\sinh(t)dt}{5}$$

which becomes, with $ u=\sinh(t) $,

$$=F(x)=-\frac 15\int \frac{u^2}{1+u^2}du$$
$$=-\frac 15(u-\arctan(u))+C$$

$$=-\frac 15\Bigl(\sqrt{25x^2-1}-\arctan(\sqrt{25x^2-1})\Bigr)+C$$

Comment: thank you for pretty big hint

Answer (score 1):

It is more convenient to just integrate by parts
\begin{align}
\int \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{25x^2}}\ dx
&= x \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{25x^2}} + \frac1{5} \int \frac1{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{25x^2}}}d(\frac1{5x})\\
&= x \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{25x^2}} +\frac15 \sin^{-1}\frac1{5x}+C
\end{align}

Comment: ‘ibp’ as ‘integration by parts’ is clear, but for the OP show a tad more?

Answer (score 0):

You are right. Differentiate the solution to get original function
$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\left( \dfrac15\sqrt{25x^2-1}-\frac15\sec^{-1}(5x)\right)=\sqrt{1-\dfrac{1}{25x^2}}$$

$$\int \sqrt{1-\dfrac{1}{25x^2}}\ dx=\dfrac15\sqrt{25x^2-1}-\frac15\sec^{-1}(5x)+c$$